# WMS not showing in QGIS 3.34.3

Tags: qgis, wms

I am using QGIS 3.34.3 Prizren. I am able to connect to WMS server (
https://www.geoportal.sa/ogc/services/NDM_WMS/Transport_NDM/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0 )

However, after connection, list of layers can be existed. When trying to add any layer from this list, it is just listed in the left panel and no display for the layer in the main screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Service isn't working at all for me (I don't have the token), so difficult to say.  One reason for layers to show as available in the menu but not show in the map is they are scale dependent.

You need to look at the GetCapabilities response ~ https://www.geoportal.sa/ogc/services/NDM_WMS/Transport_NDM/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0 for

`<MinScaleDenominator>{some value}</MinScaleDenominator>`
`<MaxScaleDenominator>{some value}</MaxScaleDenominator>`

To check if this is the issue for this service